# Solvable normal subgroup but the corresponding quotient group is not solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.
It is a well known fact that: $G$ is solvable iff $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable.

I wonder the following:
Could you give an example of a group $G$ and its normal subgroup $N$ such that $N$ is solvable but $G/N$ is not.

Comment: Tke $G=A_5\times C_5$. Then $N=C_5$ is a solvable normal subgroup, but $G/N\cong  A_5$ is not solvable.

Comment: Take any non solvable group $G$, and $N=\{e\}$. Also, I have no idea why was this question closed. How is the "duplicate" even relevant to this question?

Comment: The duplicate was my mistake, @Mark. I read too quickly . . .

Comment: $G$ any nonsolvable group, $N=\{1_G\}$

Answer (score 3):

Take any solvable group $S$, and non-solvable $G$, and consider $G×S$.

For instance,  I was thinking $A_5×C_2$ (but was beat to it in the comments).